# Corba request timeout

Tags: c++, tcp, corba

I am working on a Corba client for some time. One problem that I run in is that I am not really able to define a timeout configuration.

I am using a Mico C++ orb but it seems to be a global problem because I found noone who could describe if there is a Corba defined method to configure a request timeout.

Does anyone know of such an interface or orb initialization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Messaging section of the CORBA spec defines RelativeRequestTimeoutPolicy and RelativeRoundtripTimeoutPolicy for that. You may look at the section named "Programming client timeouts" in http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/C++-report-col19.pdf for more information.

I don't have experience with MICO, but it seems that it is supported since version [2.3.13](http://www.mico.org/pipermail/mico-announce/2008/000034.html)

Comment: policy is the magic word. Its a part of the real time corba part right. So thats something that I can lookup in the mico code. Thanks a lot that helps.

Comment: Not that it is very important but:
I just checked the CORBA 3 spec. to be sure, and request timeouts are in the Messaging section (and the IDL definitions are in the Messaging module). I think that Real Time CORBA is a separate spec.

Answer (score 1):

Policies are not real-time specific; policies permeate the core spec as well as optional features such as Real Time.  The POA uses policies, as does the ORB itself, to configure different behaviors.

As Eric Malenfant already pointed out, there are two timeout policies that are part of the Messaging aspect of CORBA that will have an effect.  However, there are also additional policies known as Sync Scope policies that affect the timeout policies as well.  I'm not sure how much MICO implements any of those.